# What's the best way to install downloaded data from market

Tags: android, database, sqlite, caching, google-play

I have a database cache that is about 3MB, and takes a long time to generate.

So my solution is to 7zip the sqlite3 database to about 500K, and put it as a separate download in the market.

Upon market download, it should unzip and copy itself to /data/data/packagename/database/.
What I do not want is any launcher activities.

What is the best way to go about this, is it possible to just detect market install event and use that?

I suspect there's a best practice somewhere, I just can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: why a separate download? why not include it?

Comment: Because I want to keep my application size as small as possible. even 500K seems fairly big for a mobile app. I want to avoid including it as much as possible.

Comment: If you force your users to download a separate app from the market, which will also take up space, I think the hassle outweighs any benefits, plus they will have that separate app installed so the 500K will be used by an app either way

Comment: The point is not if 500K is worth including or not, but rather if something like this is possible. Google has the speech library as a download, just wondering how one can go about creating something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a broadcast receiver to try to listen for PACKAGE_ADDED intent. I am not sure if the listening works before the package is actually added so you have to give it the try.

If the former doesn't work, either include it together with the app, i think 500kb is reasonable enough.. or make a splash screen to unzip it on launch.